# Using connect and mapDispatchToProps with functional components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am experimenting with Redux. I understand to dispatch action to the store from functional components, one can subscribe using `useDispatch` hook. I am dispatching action from `useEffect` and according to [react-redux doc.](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks), `dispatch` can be omitted from list of dependencies to `useEffect` because its identity is stable  .

```js
  const TriviaCategories = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_CATEGORIES", triviaCategories });
  }, []);
  return null;
};
```

If i decide to use `connect` to subscribe to the store, will the `dispatch` function identity still be stable like with `useDispatch` hook?

Comment: When using the `connect` HOC and mapping dispatch to your action creators the action creators are wrapped in a call to dispatch, so there really isn't a need to directly access the `dispatch` prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dispatch` function will always be stable as long as you continue to pass the same Redux store instance to your `<Provider store={store}>`, because `dispatch` is simply `store.dispatch`.

However, the React "hook dependencies" lint rule does not know this.  It knows that functions from React's built-in hooks (`useState` setters and `useReducer` dispatch functions) are always stable, so it can special-case and ignore those, but it has no way of knowing that the React-Redux `dispatch` function *should* be stable.  So, it will always warn that you need to add it to the effect deps array.

Because of that, you might as well just always add it to the deps array.